# Remove spaces in string, excluding these in specified between specified characters

Tags: php, preg-match, php-5.3, expression

I have a string:

```
Some string, "it's a nice string". I like it. "some other text"
```

I want remove spaces, excluding there beetween ":

```
Somestring,"it's a nice string".Ilikeit."some other text"
```

How I can goal this?

Comment: By processing the string and removing the spaces. See PHP string functions and regular expressions.

Comment: What have you tried so far? You're getting down voted for not showing any effort to do this I believe.

Comment: Yeah, I tried regular expressions but I can only remove all spaces, I have no idea how to ommit there between tags

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use regular expressions, or you could cheat and use `explode()`:

```
$text_before = 'Some string, "it\'s a nice string". I like it. "some other text"';
$text_after = array();
$text_quotes = explode('"', $text_before);
for ($i = 0, $max = count($text_quotes); $i < $max; $i++) {
    if (($i % 2) == 1) {
        $text_after[] = $text_quotes[$i];
    } else {
        $text_after[] = str_replace(' ', '', $text_quotes[$i]);
    }
}
echo implode('"', $text_after);
```

Comment: Maybe, but your solution is cleaner :)

Answer (score 0):

You may achieve it by using php str_replace function. Please check http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php

Answer (score 0):

I'm not good with regex, so this solution doesn't use any. What I would do:

```
$str = 'Some string, "it\'s a nice string". I like it. "some other text"';
$pieces = explode('"', $str);
for($i = 0; $i < count($pieces); $i += 2){ // Every other chunk is quoted
    $pieces[$i] = str_replace(' ', '', $pieces[$i]);
}
$str = implode('"', $pieces);
```

If the string starts with double quotes, php will make the first element of the `$pieces` array empty, so this should still work.