# C --- Remove all extra spaces in string excluding chars between specified characters

Tags: c, string, char

I have this string: `print     "Foo cakes      are   yum"`
I need to somehow strip all extra whitespace but leave text between quotes alone. This is what i have so far:

```
char* clean_strip(char* string)
{
    int d = 0, c = 0;
    char* newstr;
    while(string[c] != '\0'){
         if(string[c] == ' '){
            int temp = c + 1;
            if(string[temp] != '\0'){
                while(string[temp] == ' ' && string[temp] != '\0'){
                    if(string[temp] == ' '){
                        c++;
                    }
                    temp++;
                }
            }
        }
        newstr[d] = string[c];
        c++;
        d++;
     }
    return newstr;
}
```

This returns this string: `print "Foo cakes are yum"`

I need to be able to skip text between thw quotes so i get this: `print "Foo cakes      are   yum"`.

Here is the same question but for php, i need a c answer: [Remove spaces in string, excluding these in specified between specified characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8589361/remove-spaces-in-string-excluding-these-in-specified-between-specified-characte)

Please help.

Comment: Use `strtok`. It removes your specified delimiter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char* clean_strip(char* string)
{
    int d = 0, c = 0;
    char* newstr = malloc(strlen(string)+1);
    int quoted = 0;

    while(string[c] != '\0'){
        if (string[c] == '"') quoted = !quoted;

         if(!quoted && string[c] == ' '){
            int temp = c + 1;
            if(string[temp] != '\0'){
                while(string[temp] == ' ' && string[temp] != '\0'){
                    if(string[temp] == ' '){
                        c++;
                    }
                    temp++;
                }
            }
        }

        newstr[d] = string[c];
        c++;
        d++;
     }
    newstr[d] = 0;
    return newstr;
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char *input = "print     \"Foo cakes      are   yum\"";
    char *output = clean_strip(input);
    printf(output);
    free(output);
    return 0;
}
```

This will produce the output:

```
print "Foo cakes      are   yum"
```

It works by looking for the `"` character. If it's found it toggles the variable `quoted`. If `quoted` is true, then the whitespace removal is skipped.

Also, your original function never allocates memory for newstr. I added the `newstr = malloc(...)` part. It is important to allocate memory for strings before writing to them.

Comment: I get a whole bunch of errors pointing at the malloc function. Is it a c++ only function?

Comment: `malloc` is a C function. Put the line `#include <stdlib.h>` at the very top of your file.

Comment: Make sure you also have `string.h` and `stdio.h` included while you're at it.

Comment: It's also a good idea to check that `malloc()` succeeds before using the return result.

Answer (score 0):

I simplified your logic a little.

```
int main(void)
{
    char string[] = "print     \"Foo cakes      are   yum\"";
    int i = 0, j = 1, quoted=0;
    if (string[0] == '"')
    {
        quoted=1;
    }
    for(i=1; i< strlen(string); i++)
    {
        if (string[i] == '"')
        {
            quoted = 1-quoted;
        }
        string[j] = string[i];
        if (string[j-1]==' ' && string[j] ==' ' && !quoted)
        {
            ;
        }
        else
        {
            j++;
        }
    }
    string[j]='\0';
    printf("%s\n",string);
    return 0;

}
```